# Div sections shifts when i resize the window

Tags: css, html

I have placed 2 divs side by side, one conatins the logo and second contains the text fields.  When I view this page at larger resolution, everything is ok.  But, when I resize the window, the second div also gets shited and comes below the 1st div.

But I want them to stay there side by side, at any resolution. kindly provide the code solution for this.

Comment: You need to provide some code on how you are achieving this as there are a number of ways that could affect the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you use float to position them next to each other.
You can wrap around the two divs with another div of a minimum width you want the page to be viewed in.
that will stop the second one from dropping below the first one

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="logo">...</div>
    <div id="text">...</div>
</div>
```

style for it would be:

```
#wrapper { width: 980px; }
#wrapper div { float: left; }
#logo { width: 200px; }
#text { width: 780px; }
```

something like that.
if someone resizes the window to be narrower than 980px (or uses lower screen res) then you'll get horizontal scroll.

**//edit**
in response to comment you can use min-width to make it more flexible. will cause IE

```
#wrapper { min-width: 980px; }
#wrapper div { float: left; }
#logo { width: 200px; }
#text { min-width: 780px; }
```

min-width isn't supported by IE6 so you may need fix for that.

Comment: actually, setting the width of #wrapper to be fixed can cause compromise of the "fluidity" of the design. If the page is to be fixed width, its always better that the width of <body>, or of the topmost container div be set. The child nodes should not need to worry a lot about width.

Comment: agree. but kaushik hasn't provided any requirements or code sample to work with

Answer (score 0):

basically the second div needs somewhere to go if it won't fit. In your case the only option is to crop so wrap the line in a div with overflow:hidden.

Answer (score 0):

the second div slides below the first one because there is not enough width in the container to allow both of them to be placed side by side.

This can be remedied in two ways:

1. change the "overflow" property of the container node to "hidden" (or even overflow).
2. Set the "min-width" of the container. This approach however, is afflicted by special hacks required for IE. Also, a min-width approach usually cannot be done abruptly. It has to be planned from the start of page design.

Hope that helps.

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I tried keeping the total of widths 1% less (1% unused) from the total of both divs.... seems to work for me :) Myabe it is useful to someone.

CSS:

```
#Content {
width: 100%; 
height: auto; 
margin-top: 26px; 
float: left;

}
#ContentLeft {
margin-left: 5px; 
float: left; 
width: 19%;
}

#ContentMain {
width: 80%; 
margin-right: 5px; 
float: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="Content">
<div id="ContentLeft">Left menu</div>
<div id="ContentMain">Here goes the bigger content</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is just that your 10px(margin-left + margin-right) are more then 1%.
This should work:

```
#Content {
width: 100%; 
height: auto; 
margin-top: 26px; 
float: left;
}

#ContentLeft {
margin-left: 1%; 
float: left; 
width: 19%;
}

#ContentMain {
width: 79%; 
margin-right: 1%; 
float: right;
}
```