# Floating div issue upon window resize

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, overlay, css-float

As I am transitioning from using template layouts to writing my own css scripts, I have run into many issues, but there's one preventing me from continuing. I have successfully created a 3 column layout with floating divs, however upon browser re-size the right column overlays the middle div. I have imported the script found on [Div sections shifts when i resize the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892497/div-sections-shifts-when-i-resize-the-window)    with no success. Basically I want the layout to behave like the current one, at http://www.allstarselectric.com , but using %. I am using % for cross resolution support, so is there a workaround/solution, or are pixels absolutely necessary? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CSS:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #666;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.7em; 
    background-color: #4a4d51;
    background-image: url(images/templatemo_body.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: top
}

.content{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
    background-image: url(images/templatemo_body.jpg);
}


.contentbody{
float: left;
width: 70%;
height: 100%;
}



.wrapper {
  width:100%
}



.sidebar{
float: left;
width: 15%;
height: 100%;
border: 0px solid #BBB;
background-color:#dddddd;
}
.sidebar li{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}


.sidebar2{
float: left;
width: 15%;
height: 100%;
border: 0px solid #BBB;
background-color:#dddddd;
}
.sidebar2 li{
list-style-type:none;
text-align: center;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}



.chromestyle{
width: 100%;
font-weight: bold;
}
.chromestyle:after{ /*Adds margin between menu and rest of content in Firefox*/
content: "."; 
display: block; 
height: 0; 
clear: both; 
visibility: hidden;
}

/*Affects the background/menustyle*/
.chromestyle ul{
border: 0px solid #BBB;
width: 730px;
height: 45px;
background:  url(imgs/navm.jpg) center center no-repeat; /*THEME CHANGE HERE*/
padding: 0 15px;
margin: 0;
text-align: left; /*set value to "left", "center", or "right"*/
}

.chromestyle ul li{
display: inline;
}


/*Affects menu text*/


.chromestyle ul li a{
    float: left;
    display: block;
        color: #000;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: none;
}

.chromestyle ul li a:hover, .chromestyle ul li a.selected{ /*script dynamically adds a class of "selected" to the current active menu item*/
color: #fff;
background: #ff0011
 center center repeat-x; /*THEME CHANGE HERE*/
}



.current { color: #fff; background: ; }


/* ######### Style for Drop Down Menu ######### */

.dropmenudiv{
position:absolute;
top: 0;
border: 1px solid #BBB; /*THEME CHANGE HERE*/
border-bottom-width: 0;
font:normal 12px Verdana;
line-height:18px;
z-index:100;
background-color: #d5a30b;
width: 200px;
visibility: hidden;
}


.dropmenudiv a{
width: auto;
display: block;
text-indent: 3px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB; /*THEME CHANGE HERE*/
padding: 2px 0;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
}

* html .dropmenudiv a{ /*IE only hack*/
width: 100%;
}

.dropmenudiv a:hover{ /*THEME CHANGE HERE*/
background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Allstars Electric</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="electricians," />
<meta name="description" content="Electrical Contractor DFW" />


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/drop.js">
</script>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style2 {color: #FFFF00}
.style3 {
    font-size: 36px
}
-->
</style>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
function JumpToIt(list) {
    var newPage = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value
    if (newPage != "None") {
        location.href=newPage
    }
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>



</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="sidebar" id="sidebar"><li>home</li></div>

<div class="contentbody">
<center>
<div class="chromestyle" id="chromemenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="specialoffers.html">Special Offers</a></li>
<li><a href="#" rel="dropmenu2">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>  
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#" rel="dropmenu3">Themes</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<!--1st drop down menu -->                                                   
<div id="dropmenu1" class="dropmenudiv">
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">2</a>
<a href="#">3</a>
<a href="#">4</a>
<a href="#">5</a>
</div>


<!--2nd drop down menu -->                                                
<div id="dropmenu2" class="dropmenudiv" style="width: 150px;">
<a href="electrical.html">Electrical</a>
<a href="hvac.html">Heating & Air Conditioning</a>
</div>

<!--3rd drop down menu -->                                                   
<div id="dropmenu3" class="dropmenudiv" style="width: 150px;">
<a href="http://www.allstarselectric.com/index.html">Dark</a>
<a href="http://www.allstarselectric.com/light/index.html">Light</a>
</div>
<!-- Dropdown End -->

<br><tr>text/other</br></tr>
</center>
</body>
</div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar2" id="sidebar2"><li>Home</li>


<script type="text/javascript">

cssdropdown.startchrome("chromemenu")

</script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you have a fixed width set for .chromestyle ul. Change that width to a %, and that should fix your problem.

Comment: When I do that, the background for my drop-down goes to mid-page and the li items wrap onto new lines. Any ideas for that?

Answer (score 0):

The first answer to the article you linked provides you with the most reasonable solution: "You can wrap around the two divs with another div of a minimum width you want the page to be viewed in." There isn't much point in trying to fit a page to a 320x240 browser; scroll bars can't be avoided in that kind of resolution.

Something like this

```
.foowrap { min-width: 550px; width: 100%; overflow:auto; }
.foo { width:30%; float:left; }

<div class="foowrap">
    <div class="foo">bar</div>
    <div class="foo">baz</div>
    <div class="foo">bum</div>
</div>
```

Then make sure that the total minimum width of the divs inside (class foo in the example) is not more than the min-width you set. Watch out for borders especially.

By the way, you have two `</body>` and you're using `<center>`, both of which are things you should avoid. This bit doesn't make much sense either: `<br><tr>text/other</br></tr>`

Comment: The br/tr/text/other was simply to test if on column's contents would affect the other divs. And when I implement the above code, I still face the issue of overlapping sections (The right section overlaps the middle). Upon browser resize I want the scroll bar to appear, but I want the layout to be cross-resolution. Also, I failed at finding a css alternative for centering the dropdown menu.

- Thank you for pointing out the </body> tag to me, I completely overlooked that!

Comment: I'm not really able to help you with your problem beyond my post at the moment as I don't understand what part of your code sample you are talking about. Try to cut it down to the relevant divs and their styles. As for centering, read this short post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4432419/1311593

Comment: You can view it here:
Before applying above code:
http://www.allstarselectric.com/scratch012/
After:
http://allstarselectric.com/2/

Comment: Are you just trying to center the middle div on the page? The "overlap" effect is created because the three divs have their widths and if the middle one doesn't get enough space for its full width, it will get an overflow which is hidden. Try adding `overflow:auto;` to `.contentbody` and you will see what I mean. Plus, in `</center> </body> </div> </div>`, the wrapper is closed. Remove one of the `</div>` here.

Comment: I just tried that, then played with it a bit more to if it would work, with no success. If we start from scratch, what would the code be for a simple 3 column layout, a sidebar for advertisements/deal/certifications on either side of content?
Also, using percents were recommended from a friend. Is there really any significant advantage over using px? I'm new to css, just finished learning HTML, so please bear with me.

Comment: You are using the correct approach there - the question is just whether at small browser sizes, should the sidebars or should the main content disappear? It would probably make sense to give all of them a min-width and `overflow:auto`. Although advertising sidebars could be set to a fixed pixel width. All you need to do is, make your browser window really small and think about what you would want to see at that kind of browser size. % can help you get the same layout across different window sizes in some cases, fixed px width in others.

Comment: When I give overflow:auto to all of the class's, it just adds more scroll bars as well as moves the default to the middle of the page, which I thought not possible until now.

Comment: I just came across this:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-fixed-layout-31-fixed-fixed-fixed/